# A Tkinter Entry with boundaries

Tags: python, tkinter, boundary

Currently, I am working on a `Tkinter` GUI. In this GUI, I would like to include an `Entry` field where users can only enter numbers between two boundaries (for instance, a number between 0.0 and 200.0). I have looked into the `validatecommand` option, but this still does not provide me a solution. Is there somebody who can help me to create a `Tkinter` `Entry` with boundaries?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the user has entered "1" (clearly between 0 and 200) and then presses delete so that there's nothing in the entry field, what do you expect to happen? An empty string is not a number, and therefore not between 0 and 200. Do you want to prevent them from completely clearing the entry?

Comment: Will the lower bound always be zero, or could it be 100, or could it be negative? There are a lot of usability ramifications for allowing some numbers and disallowing others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value by .get() method and then write an if statement to generate an error or reset the value by .set() method when limits are exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

`tkinter Entry validation` allows to validate characters typed in the `Entry` field.
I do not know if the validation process built in `tkinter` allows to validate the entire entered value for being within a given range; however, you can use a common `if-else` test for that:

In the following example, **the values of each entered character in the entry is validated for being a digit**. then, upon retrieving the value `entry.get`, **the value is checked to ascertain it is within the desired range**, and printed in the console; if not, a `ValueError` is raised.

the line `entry._get, entry.get = entry.get, _get_only_in_range` makes a private copy of `entry.get`, then monkey patches it to inject the desired behavior
A better way is probably to write a class to encapsulate the behavior specific to your entry.

```
import tkinter as tk


def only_numbers(char):    # validates each character as it is entered in the entry
    if char.isdigit():
        return True
    else:
        root.bell()
        return False

def _get_only_in_range():
    num = int(entry._get())   # uses the private copy of the original entry.get
    if 0 <= num < 200:
        return num
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'value {num} must be between 0 and 200')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    validation = root.register(only_numbers)
    entry = tk.Entry(root, validate="key", validatecommand=(validation, '%S'))
    entry._get = entry.get           # make private copy of original get
    entry.get = _get_only_in_range   # calling entry.get now calls _get_only_in_range to validate the value
    entry.pack()
    tk.Button(root, text='get value', command=lambda: print(entry.get())).pack()  # here get points to _get_only_in_range
    root.mainloop()
```